# Error while selecting listitem

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Hey guys I'm trying to update a column value of a particular list item. but when i try to select the list item it throws NullPointerException. it works fine in other cases, but here it won't. below is my code and the stack trace

I've commented out where the error occurs

```
public class Quick extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText addAmount;
ListView selectCategory;
Button OK,CANCEL;
DBHelper dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);
AddListItems addListItems=new AddListItems();
String[] columns;
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Add Instant Expenses");
    setContentView(R.layout.quick);
    addAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.howmuchspend);
    selectCategory = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    OK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAddQuick);
    CANCEL = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCancelQuick);
    displayList();
    selectCategory.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            add(id); /* error here */
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item with id " + id + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    CANCEL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Quick.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    OK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Quick.this, Quick.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
public void add(long itemId){
    final int finAmount=Integer.parseInt(addAmount.getText().toString());
    addListItems.addTotal(finAmount, itemId);
}
@TargetApi(11)
private void displayList() {
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = dbHelper.getListItems();
    if(cursor==null){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Quick.this,AddListItems.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        columns = new String[]{DBHelper.KEY_CATEGORY, DBHelper.KEY_AMOUNT};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.category, R.id.amount};
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor, columns, to, 0);
        selectCategory.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    }
}
```

}

and here's the stack trace

```
02-24 12:34:56.587    2610-2610/com.example.rajkumar.budgetanalysis E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rajkumar.budgetanalysis, PID: 2610
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:256)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at com.example.rajkumar.budgetanalysis.DBHelper.addAmount(DBHelper.java:95)
        at com.example.rajkumar.budgetanalysis.AddListItems.addTotal(AddListItems.java:48)
        at com.example.rajkumar.budgetanalysis.Quick.add(Quick.java:59)
        at com.example.rajkumar.budgetanalysis.Quick$1.onItemLongClick(Quick.java:36)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2979)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2928)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

DBHelper class:

```
package com.example.rajkumar.budgetanalysis;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
SeparateBudget data;
public static final String TABLE_NAME="my_budget";
public static final String ID="id";
public static final String OWNER_NAME="owner_name";
public static final String BUDGET_NAME="budget_name";
public static final String BUDGET_LIMIT="budget_limit";
static final String DB_NAME="TABLE_BUDGET.db";
static final int DB_VERSION=1;
public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
public static final String KEY_DATE="_date";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY="list_cat";
public static final String KEY_AMOUNT="list_amount";
public static final String TABLE2_NAME = "my_expenses";
public static final String USER_NAME="user_name";
public static final String PASSWORD="password";
public static final String TABLE_LOGIN="login_table";
public static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + ID +" INTEGER "+
        " PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , " + OWNER_NAME + " TEXT ,"+ BUDGET_NAME +" TEXT ,"
        + BUDGET_LIMIT + " VARCHAR );";
public static final String CREATE_TABLE2="create table " + TABLE2_NAME + " ( " +
        KEY_ROWID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , " + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT UNIQUE ," +
        KEY_AMOUNT + " VARCHAR );";
public static final String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE="create table "+TABLE_LOGIN+" ( "+USER_NAME+" VARCHAR , "+
        PASSWORD+" VARCHAR );";
public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE2);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    Log.d("database handler", "Database created");
}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE2_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public void addData(SeparateBudget separateBudget){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(OWNER_NAME,separateBudget.get_owner());
    values.put(BUDGET_NAME,separateBudget.get_budget_name());
    values.put(BUDGET_LIMIT, separateBudget.get_budget_limit());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public void createCategory(String list_cat,String list_amt){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CATEGORY,list_cat);
    values.put(KEY_AMOUNT,list_amt);
    db.insert(TABLE2_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();
}
public Cursor getListItems(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor=db.query(TABLE2_NAME,new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_AMOUNT},null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToLast();
    }
    return cursor;
}
public SeparateBudget getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToLast()) {
        data = new SeparateBudget(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
    }
    return data;
}
public void deleteData(SeparateBudget sep){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(sep.get_id())});
}
public void deldata(long position){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE2_NAME,KEY_ROWID + "=" +position,null );
}
public void addAmount(String amount,long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE2_NAME+" SET "+KEY_AMOUNT+"="+amount+", WHERE "+KEY_ROWID+" = "+id+" ;");
    db.close();
}
```

}

Comment: error log points to database error though

Comment: Error is in `DBHelper` class. Please post that.

Comment: @ Rohith 5k2 thanks man here's the DBHelper

Answer (score 0):

So in the activity called Quick, you have the line `DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);` change that line to `DBHelper dbHelper;` Then, after setContentView method in onCreate add `dbHelper = new DBHelper(this)`
The reason it didn't work with your code is because Context isn't created until onCreate is called.

Comment: that worked man. thanks! I'd've upvoted ur answer but you know the reputation thing..